# Diskpart commands from WinRT application in C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, cmd, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing **WinRT application** in which I wanted to **fire few commands in "DiskPart" CMD tool**, within the application.

**Development Environment is in C# + XAML**

for example, I want to fire `list disk` command which is a DiskPart command, that gives details of disks exists on hardDrive.

Simply, my WinRT application will let user,

- **format a partition** of hardDrive
- copying some contents into/from the specific partition

on specific events like button click & etc

Comment: WinRT applications are restricted, you're not going to be able to do this.

Comment: A a console you create WILL NOT run a tool like DiskPart and there isn't a way to do it.  You can launch a new cmd window but as Nicholas suggests WInRT applications are restricted and you won't be able to do this for that reason also.

Comment: @nicholasW: I was afraid of this, but Thought there might be a solution.

Comment: Is there any other way to format disk partition through WinRT App.

Comment: You could have a service installed on the machine that communicates with the WinRT app, but other than that I don't think so. Also, there's a good chance that would be a *huge* security hole.

Comment: @NateDiamond: which kind of service..? can you help me with example. and is that service provided by root API or any third party service.?

Comment: [These kind of Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there's no current way to access the Diskpart commands from inside the WinRT sandbox.

There's also restrictions on local network loopbacks in order to hinder the "app talking to a service outside the sandbox" for security reasons as well.